# Get node of data from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

i'm trying to get data from firebase and i'm little stuck with that.
[image]

i'm trying to get the all SemaA data
i did it like that but it not give me nothing

```
firebase.database().ref('Courses/'+departmentId+'/SemA'),
```

i can specific to do (but i don't want it)

```
firebase.database().ref('Courses/'+departmentId+'/SemA/java'),
```

i also wnated to get the black sign and red sign in two different queries and run into loop to get the data from there
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to loop over the courses in a semester:

```
var semesterRef = firebase.database().ref('Courses/'+departmentId+'/SemA')
semesterRef.on('child_added', function(courseSnapshot) {
    console.log(courseSnapshot.key);
});
```

Comment: that's exactly what i wanted!!! it works. i edited my answer if you can see in the post. i want also to loop into that and get these values, how can i do that?